# Output PDF not generated - XeLaTeX

Tags: xetex, output-directory

I'am using `XeLaTeX` in `MikTeX2.9` and `Win10`, and all the files are placing in a centralized point like some IP `172.00.00.0`. I'm compiling the files like the below format:

```
c:\users\latex>xelatex \\172.00.00.0\test.tex
```

Above was working, but all the subfiles, e.g., `.aux`, `.log` and `.pdf` file was kept in the folder `c:\users\latex`, but I want all the files should be in `\\172.00.00.0`, kindly advise that is it possible? Please

I also tried with

```
c:\users\latex\xelatex \\172.00.00\test_samp.tex -aux-directory=\\172.00.00.3\test -output-directory=\\172.00.00.0\test
```

But got the error as:

```
MiKTeX cannot retrieve attributes for the file '\\172.00.00.0\test\intcalc.sty'.

The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:

  C:\Users\Latex\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\miktex\log\xelatex.log
```

Comment: switch into the folder of test.tex and compile from there.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Many thanks, I've crated a `subfolder` named as `test` in `\\172.00.00.0`, and placed the `.tex` file into that folder and compile it, but still all the files are placed in `c:\users\latex`, please advise

Comment: I didn't write, "create a folder", but "switch into the folder". Do `cd \\172.00.00.0`  or whatever you need to change the directory.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I tried with `cd "\\172.16.100.3"` in `CMD` prompt, but I got the error as `CMD does not support UNC paths as current directories.`

Comment: Isn't `\\172.00.00.0` also mounted as a drive letter on your PC? Try that instead.